# postgreSQL ranking query with the given user_id

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, yii2

I am trying to **get rank of a user** by their two dimension params: `donation sum` and `total donor count`.

My rank formula is: `rank of [rank of donation_sum + rank of donor_count / 2]`

Sample table:

```
donation_id | user_id | donor_id | donation_sum
-----------------------------------------------
1 | 1 | 1 | 10
2 | 1 | 2 | 5
3 | 2 | 3 | 10
4 | 3 | 1 | 50
...
```

As you see, some donors make donation to different users, so I used `sum(donation_sum)` and `count(distinct(donation_id))` to get exact rankings

I am able to get list of ranking separately by donation sum and total donor count with 2 sql but my need is to get a user rank with that formula above by given `user_id` in postgreSQL v. 9.4

Do you have any solution for it? so I will use that sql query in a Yii2 PHP framework

Thanks

---

Edit:
We added donation_date to the tbl_donation and modified actual query as below:

### is it true usage of where donation_date?

```
    with list as (
        select 
        s.runner_id, sum, count, rank_sum, rank_count,
        (rank_sum+ rank_count)::float/ 2 as rank_avg,
        row_number() over (order by rank_sum) as rank
    from (
        select *, rank() over (order by sum desc) rank_sum
        from (
            select runner_id, sum(donation_sum)
            from tbl_donation
where donation_date >= '2015-01-01'
            group by 1
            ) s
        ) s
    join (  
        select *, rank() over (order by count desc) rank_count
        from (
            select runner_id, count(distinct(donator_id))
            from tbl_donation
where donation_date >= '2015-01-01'
            group by 1
            ) c
        ) c
    using (runner_id)
    )
    select rank
    from list
    where runner_id = 251;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two rankings in separate subqueries:

```
select 
    s.user_id, sum, count, rank_sum, rank_count,
    (rank_sum+ rank_count)::float/ 2 as rank_avg,
    row_number() over (order by rank_sum) as rank
from (
    select *, rank() over (order by sum desc) rank_sum
    from (
        select user_id, sum(donation_sum)
        from donations
        group by 1
        ) s
    ) s
join (  
    select *, rank() over (order by count desc) rank_count
    from (
        select user_id, count(distinct(donation_id))
        from donations
        group by 1
        ) c
    ) c
using (user_id);

 user_id | sum | count | rank_sum | rank_count | rank_avg | rank 
---------+-----+-------+----------+------------+----------+------
       3 | 100 |     1 |        1 |          2 |      1.5 |    1
       1 |  30 |     2 |        2 |          1 |      1.5 |    2
       2 |  20 |     1 |        3 |          2 |      2.5 |    3
(3 rows)
```

If you want to select `rank` for a single `user_id` use `with query`, e.g.:

```
with list as (
    -- place here the above query
)
select rank
from list
where user_id = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. It worked here and it gives list of users' ranks but some suspicious here

Comment: Hey @klin you make me happy indeed, thanks. just a question:  
row1: rank 1,5 and 
row2: rank 1.5
how can get 1 and 2 for the users? 

for example where user_id = 1 returns 1,5 but for the rank list it must be 2 (because user_id =3 is rank 1)

Comment: its like I need row number :) can you add a column for the row number? Thanks

Comment: You can add *clear* ranking (as integer number) by adding `row_number()` and `order by`, see the edited answer.

Comment: I meant "like row number" because when I use where at the end it returns only one row and its row number always 1

I have changed `using (user_id);` with `using (user_id) where user_id = 1;`

@klin Your solution is great I can use foreach to get rank order but I hope no need to it because I will not list of users by rank, I will show a user rank on his profile page; foreach is not seem a nice solution. Any idea? 
Thanks

Comment: I forget to add donation_date column to the sample table. Now tried to calculate rank by current year for a user (#251) but it shows 12**.5** as rank, can we show as ordinal numbers? (#12 or #13)

Comment: I have shared the last real query on the question.

Comment: list view is ok, nothing wrong with it, my mistake. if that the donation_date usage is true everything will be solved. Thanks

Comment: I found the problem. The `rank` must be `rank_avg` otherwise it list by `donation_sum` only. I have changed it with `rank_avg` but gave error, any idea?